# Jasmine testing methods inside .done or .then

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

Wondering if anyone can help me - I'm trying to test my js using Jasmine (1.3) and I can't figure out the best way to test any method calls inside a .then or a .done method.

example code to explain:

```
Backbone.View.extend({

 myMethod: function () {
   this.something.done(function () {
    this.doSomethingElse();
   }.bind(this));
  }

 })
```

I'd like to write a test that check that this.doSomethingElse was called.

I was looking around at jasmine.async and a waitsFor/runs set up but I'm not sure how it fits into external code i.e. I'm not going to call done() inside my actual code to get my test working. Also if I mock out the done method on this.something then I'm not longer testing the actual implementation, right?

I'm just missing how things fit together. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it!

**Update: based on feedback below I've now tried the following**

Hey, thanks for the answer - I think maybe I don't have the last part correct - have tried 2 different ways, both initial pass but then fail after a second or 2.

```
   it('calls doSomethingElse on done',function () {
     var mockDeferred = $.Deferred();

      myView.something = mockDeferred;
      spyOn(myView,'doSomethingElse');
      mockDeferred.resolve();

    waitsFor(function () {
      expect(myView.doSomethingElse).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

  });
```

And also:

```
it('calls doSomethingElse on done',function () {
  var mockDeferred = $.Deferred(),
      someTrigger = false;

  myView.something = mockDeferred;
  spyOn(myView,'doSomethingElse');

  runs(function () {
    mockDeferred.resolve();
    someTrigger =  true;
  });

  waitsFor(function () {
    someTrigger =  true;
  });

  runs(function () {
    expect(myView.doSomethingElse).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });


});
```

In both instances the test will pass originally but then timeout to a failure after a second or 2.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test the example function you described, I would do the following *within your test*:

- Create a new deferred object (I'll call it `mockDeferred`)
- Pass `mockDeferred` into your code under test so that it is now `this.something` in your example
- Spy on the `doSomethingElse` function
- Call `myMethod()`
- Call `resolve()` on `mockDeferred`
- Assert that `doSomethingElse` was called

**Edit based on OP's Update:**

I don't see anywhere in either of your examples where you are calling `myView.myMethod()` within your test; make sure you do that. I whipped up an example that you can reference [here](https://github.com/thompsnm/jasmine-1-3-async-example).

As an aside, I'm surprised the second example you tried passes initially. Maybe because you have some code outside of a `runs()` block?

Comment: thanks for the comment have updated the question above with how I've tried your approach. Both ways are failing after a timeout so if you have any feedback I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry for the belated response, check out my updated answer and let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Related problem**

> Spying on a method inside `.then` and expecting `.toHaveBeenCalled` fails

**Solution**:

> run test inside `fakeAsync` and run `tick()` before the `expect`

Service:

```
getFirebaseDoc() {   
  this.db.firestore.doc('some-doc').get()
    .then(this.getFirebaseDocThen)
    .catch(this.getFirebaseDocCatch);
}
```

Unit testing:

```
it('should call getFirebaseDocThen', fakeAsync(() => {            // note `fakeAsync`
    spyOn(service, 'getFirebaseDocThen');
    spyOn(service.db.firestore, 'doc').and.returnValue({
      get: (): any => {
        return new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any): any => {
          return resolve({ exists: true });
        });
      },
    });
    service.getFirebaseDoc();
    tick();                                                       // note `tick()`
    expect(service.getFirebaseDocThen).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```